# Change height and width of Flyout in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I am using a Flyout element in my UWP app as:

```
<Flyout Placement="Full"/>
```

This opens the flyout in the centre of the app as desired. But I am unable to change the height and width of the flyout. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the below code should work for what you need.

```
private void Flyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{         
    Flyout f = sender as Flyout;
    Style s = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Style { TargetType = typeof(FlyoutPresenter) };
    s.Setters.Add(new Setter(MinHeightProperty, "200"));        
    s.Setters.Add(new Setter(MinWidthProperty, "200"));
    f.FlyoutPresenterStyle = s;
}
```

Comment: This is a choice. @Pulkit Mehta If you did not quite understand what it is. Please see [FlyoutPresenter styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299125.aspx). This way actually changes the minHeight and minWidth in the style. I also suggested that you could use Popup control directly. It has height and width property.

Answer (score 12):

XAML equivalent to the accepted answer.

(Note: OP posted a Flyout - not a MenuFlyout):

```html
<Flyout>
  ...
  <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
      <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200" />
      <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="200" />
    </Style>
  </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
  ...
</Flyout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer and upvoted your (also correct) answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I want to add, that even if you resize the flyout, the content will be placed in a horizontal scrollviewer. This means, if you place a `TextBox` inside, it will enlarge infinitely depending on its content. The problem is [also described on microsoft forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef4b2b75-6356-42d1-8a6d-434ee56c8c0d/why-does-the-flyout-not-resize-sensibly?forum=w81prevwCsharp).

In order to fix, you can add:

```xml
<Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
    <!--Disable infinite flyout width-->
    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    </Style>
</Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
```

This does not work with properties directly set to the Flyout [for some reason](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5164).